# Laravel 8: Form Validation One of the two field is Required

Tags: laravel, forms, validation, laravel-8

I want to have a form validation that will accepts the data, only if 1 of 2 input fields is filled up.
thank you guys.

Comment: what have you tried, please post

Comment: Can you please share the code?

Comment: Have you tried `required_without`? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required-without

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please make sure you add more details of your work and troubleshooting. SO is not a place where you could ask "Do it for me". Make sure you are clear with your requirement and also understand that we should need some info to get your issue solved. A plain direct question wont yeild you any help other than downvotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer below code for validation-one-of-the-two-field-is-required

```
$rules = array(
    'text_one' => 'required_without:text_two',
    'text_two' => 'required_without:text_one', 
);
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
```